creating editable fields in mathml
I am creating an ios app that serves as a math editor. My current plan is to use mathml and create editable fields for different components (frac, sqrt, etc). However, I don't know of a way to do it. Right now, I have a wkwebview that renders mathml that is inputed.
I have tried to insert edible feilds into mathml but that doesn't seem to work. My goel is to have something like word where there are dotted boxes for the editable fields, but I don't know if that was implemented from scratch or if there is a convention that I don't know about. Does anyone have any ideas to go about this/if there is a better avenue than mathml?
